# Directory not appearing in GitHub windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I recently used the git console to push existing source from my machine into a new repository, where it is now showing correctly on git on the web.

I can't get the repository to appear in git for windows.

Obviously the directory has had `git init` applied (as part of the initial push) but I tried it again just to be sure. No joy.

Is there an additional step required to make a repository appear in git for windows? nb. I don't want to clone as that would mean a lot of hassle backing up source, deleting it, pulling it and re-applying changes that have been done in the meantime.

Comment: What are you referring to with “git desktop”? Is it a command-line Git client, or is it “GitHub for Windows”?

Comment: Windows. I'll clarify that.

Comment: Note that “Git for Windows” and “GitHub for Windows” are still very different things, the latter being a client especially for GitHub.

Comment: I see, so there's no intuitive way to add existing source to a new repository (which can only be done via console) and then have that repository appear in the windows app (without some rigmarole of deleting so you can clone back down what you just pushed up)?